# Find a simplified form for $n!+(n-1)!+(n-2)!+(n-3)!+ \dots +1!$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find a simplified form for $n!+(n−1)!+(n−2)!+(n−3)!+\dots+1!$ .

By simplified, I mean that there should not be "..." in the equation.

If there isn't one, prove it. Thanks!

Edit 1: Is it possible not to have $\sum$ in it?

Comment: This may not be satisfactory but: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html Also another way to say simplify is "in closed form".

Comment: $\sum_{a=1}^n a!$ has no "..." in it.

Comment: Here have some forms http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28a%21%2C+a%3D1...n%29

Comment: You can use the gamma function, turn that expression into a single integral by linearity, and use the geometric sum to avoid having a $\sum$ in the integrand... that avoids the $\sum$ but, is that simplfied? not really... you'd get $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \cdot \left(\frac{t^{n+1}-t}{t-1}\right) dt $$

Comment: Even a single summand didn't have a simple form until the "$!$" notation was introduced!

Comment: Although the Mathworld article pointed out by Kieran already mentions it, I'd like to explicitely reference http://oeis.org/A007489 here.

Answer (score 2):

This number is just
$$1111\cdots1111$$
with $n+1$ digits in [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Comment: Ok, still has $\dots$ in it...

Answer (score -3):

∑(2-k)!

This is a simplified form of n!+(n−1)!+(n−2)!+(n−3)!+...+1!

Comment: I disagree that a summation form is simplified; in any case it is wrong for any limits on the summation so reasonable you felt it safe to exclude them.

Comment: Alright I was unsure of that.

Comment: Sum[k!, {k, 1, n}] has a closed form ... which is not very nice and be sure that this is an understatement. The summation form is the simplification.